# Calling NSString method on a String in Swift

Tags: nsstring, swift

Apple's Swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) states that

> If you are working with the Foundation framework in Cocoa or Cocoa Touch, the entire NSString API is available to call on any String value you create

If I have a String object eg

```
var newString: String = "this is a string"
```

How do I perform NSString operations like `containsString` on my String var?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After doing some research, it looks like `containsString` is not a `String` function, but can be accessed by bridging to an `NSString`.

Under Apple's Documentation on [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html), it says that

> Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString
>   class. This means that anywhere you use an NSString object, you can
>   use a Swift String type instead and gain the benefits of both types

But it appears that only some of NSString's functions are accessible without explicitly bridging. To bridge to an NSString and use any of its functions, the following methods work:

```
 //Example Swift String var
    var newString:String = "this is a string"

    //Bridging to NSString
    //1
    (newString as NSString).containsString("string")
    //2
    newString.bridgeToObjectiveC().containsString("string")
    //3
    NSString(string: newString).containsString("string")
```

All three of these work.
It's interesting to see that only some `NSString` methods are available to `Strings` and others need explicit bridging. This may be something that is built upon as Swift develops.

Answer (score 9):

The methods are the same, but they just use swift's syntax instead. For example:

```
var newString: String = "this is a string"
newString = newString.stringByAppendingString(" that is now longer")
println(newString)
```

instead of:

```
NSString* newString = @"this is a string";
newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@" that is now longer"];
NSLog(newString);
```

Note:

Not all of NSString's methods can be called on String. Some you have to bridge to NSString first like so:

```
newString.bridgeToObjectiveC().containsString("string")
```

Comment: It's only really worthwhile to use NSString where Swift's builtin `String` type doesn't provide a solution. You can append strings in Swift with the `+` and `+=` operators, so `stringByAppendingString` is just syntactic salt. (Or whatever you call the opposite of syntactic sugar ... it just makes your code longer and less readable.)

Comment: That's a good point. I was just trying to find a simple NSString method to use as an example.

Comment: I agree, I would like to use `String` rather than `NSString` whenever possible. While it looks like there are several `String` operations such as `stringByAppendingString` above, `containsString` is not a method on `String` and would need conversion to an `NSString` in order to do so.

Comment: Which is odd. This is what the docs say about the relationship of String and NSString: "Swift’s String type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation’s NSString class. If you are working with the Foundation framework in Cocoa or Cocoa Touch, the entire NSString API is available to call on any String value you create"

Comment: The wording is confusing because it makes it seem that all NSString methods are available for Strings. But it looks like it can be done with a `bridgeToObjectiveC()` statement added. This line works for me: `newString.bridgeToObjectiveC().containsString("string")`

Answer (score 4):

So what you actually have to do is this

```
var str:NSString = "Checkcontains"
str.containsString("ckc")
```

Notice how the declaration of an explicit NSString is put there. Then you can use the containsString method. If you only use var and do not set it as an NSString then you have problems.

Comment: Looks like you're correct. After running some tests in Playground, it looks like `containsString` is not a valid method for `String` and needs conversion to a `NSString` in order to do so. `newString.bridgeToObjectiveC().containsString("string")` or `NSString(string: newString).containsString("string")` both did the trick for me.

Answer (score -5):

You can call any NSString method on a Swift String object; under the hood, the two objects are 'toll-free bridged'. Thus, you can just do:

```
var newString = "this is a string"
if newString.containsString("string") {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case. It just errors with "string doesn't have a member containsString"

Comment: Also, the bridging is **NOT** toll-free. If you do it a non-trivial amount, expect to see lots of time spent in `ext.Foundation.Swift.String._bridgeToObjectiveC(Swift.String)() -> ObjectiveC.NSString` when you profile your code in Instruments. Bridged, yes, sort-of. Toll-free bridged, *definitely not.*