# swift string to nsstring convertion

Tags: php, ios, nsstring

I have an app that has to send a string from one `viewcontroller` to another. I am using `prepareforsegue` which works fine i can print the var out on the other viewcontroller in a `UILabel`.

But now I am trying to send it to my php script which communicates with my database. The problem is I am receiving the var that is being send over as var helpCode:string?

Then the function runs which is NSString and I can't get it to work. I have tested it by just typing the phrase in the function as NSString and i get the correct response from the server. But when I set it up as it has to be with variables i get a fatal error because it is sending nil. When I try to send it as NSString i get string can't be converted to NSString. How can I do this?

I see lots of solutions for nsstring to string but not the other way around. Or am i doing something else wrong.

Comment: have you checked on this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006549/calling-nsstring-method-on-a-string-in-swift

Comment: yes i have seen that one, but it is not clear to me why it should say containing string and then you give a value. What value should it look at if it should all be dynamic. That view controller shouldn't know what string to look for. This is taking all the dynamics out of the solution of passing over vars.

Comment: In general you can do this string as NSString, but you can show your code so we can see what are you talking about.