# How a struct is getting converted as an object using AnyObject in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

In the following example **testString** is declared as an object of **String** which is a struct. But we are able to assign as a object using **AnyObject**. How the struct to object conversion is happening in swift?

```
let testString:String = "Hello World" 
let testObject:AnyObject = testString 
print("My test object\(testObject)") // this works!
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006549/calling-nsstring-method-on-a-string-in-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638879/swift-strings-and-memory-addresses. Note that the bridging works only if Foundation is imported.

Answer (score 1):

It works because the compiler has special knowledge about `String` and `NSString`. String in Swift is bridgeable to NSString in ObjC. You can examine its dynamic type:

```
let testString:String = "Hello World" 
let testObject:AnyObject = testString 
print("My test object \(testObject.dynamicType)") // object_NSContiguousString
```

`object_NSContiguousString` is a private class in the `NSString` cluster.

Doing so with your own custom struct doesn't work:

```
struct Person {
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
}

let testPerson = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith")
let testObject: AnyObject = testPerson // error
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift and Objective C are not independent. In Swift you can able to use NSString.
 In your case during compilation an internal bridge is established between testString and converted to NSString type which allows you to store testString into testObject