# String to NSString briding regarding documentation doesn't work

Tags: swift

Documentation issue:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

> NOTE
>
> Swift’s String type is bridged with Foundation’s NSString class.
>   Foundation also extends String to expose methods defined by NSString.
>   This means, if you import Foundation, you can access those NSString
>   methods on String without casting.
>
> For more information about using String with Foundation and Cocoa, see
>   Bridging Between String and NSString.

The question is what did they mean? Should this feature work?

```
import Foundation

class A {
    func doSome() {
        "".isEqual(to: "q")
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile!

Only this works:

```
import Foundation

class A {
    func doSome() {
        ("" as? NSString)?.isEqual(to: "q")
    }
}
```

but `as?` is a **casting** operation

and without `import Foundation` `NSString` isn't defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling NSString method on a String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006549/calling-nsstring-method-on-a-string-in-swift)

Comment: @nayem there is no answer

Comment: Actually, the description of accepted answer on the question points to the thing you've to consider. There is no solution without type casting for your code.

Comment: @nayem the problem is about `import Foundation` and documentation

Comment: So you are saying the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006549/calling-nsstring-method-on-a-string-in-swift) isn't a possible duplicate, right? The documentation isn't thorough I think. And what problem the `import Foundation` brings to the table here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Swift documentation will be improved.

https://forums.swift.org/t/string-to-nsstring-briding-and-objc-method-calling/32364

Answer (score 1):

While casting string to NSString you will get a warning

> Conditional cast from 'String' to 'NSString' always succeeds

You can't get the access of the method `isEqual(to: "q")` from string because this is overridden in String class as well. While overriding they remove the label `to:` in the String. So, you can call this method like `isEqual("q")`. Both the methods are same with only minor difference.

You can see almost all other methods are overridden as it is in `String` class. But for this method they just vanished the label.

Comment: `isEqual(_: )` is a part of `NSObjectProtocol`. `isEqual(to: )` is a part of `NSString`. The same behavior for other specific NSString methods. For example, `open var doubleValue: Double { get }`

Comment: Exactly! if both the classes/protocols ( NSObjectProtocol and NSString) have the same method then this thing will happen. e.g. hasPrefix method is available in both of them so whenever you call it 'NSObjectProtocol' will be called in case of string but 'NSString' will be called in case of NSString. If any method which is available only in one class then it will be called. e.g. isProxy() is available only in NSObjectProtocol it means only this method will be called inside of NSObjectProtocol in either(NSString, String) way.

Answer (score 1):

A **bridge** cast is `as` without question or exclamation mark.

```
("" as NSString).isEqual(to: "q")
```

And an optional bridge cast is

```
let string : String? = ""
(string as NSString?)?.isEqual(to: "q")
```

Comment: definitely no. Please, read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/operator_declarations .as? as, as! are the same in the table

Comment: You're right, my bad. Nevertheless for some APIs you have to do the bridge cast explicitly.